# c# unable to kill process

Tags: c#, batch-file

Basically I am trying to make a program that will be able to launch and close a .bat file. I have managed to get it to launch the bat file, however I am unable to figure out how to get it to close the .bat file.

Here is the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Launcher
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void LaunchProcess()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\example.bat";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that to kill the process I would have to use `myProcess.Kill();` however I am unsure how to add it to the code, as if I was to re-call the 'launchprocess' then the myProcess would be overwritten

Comment: Just a little note: `"C:\example.bat"` might need to be changed to `"C:\\example.bat"`

Comment: That starts Cmd.exe to execute the .bat file.  So start cmd.exe yourself and you can kill it, use "/c example.bat" for the argument.  That isn't exactly enough to *also* ensure that you kill any process(es) that were started by the .bat file.  Hard to do reliably, you'll need to use a job object or rely on the taskkill /t option.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses a local variable to store the process information and doesn't save it for later operations.  If you want to keep this as a static method then return the `Process` as a result:

```
public static class MyProcess
{
    public static void LaunchProcess()
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\example.bat";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            return myProcess;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            myProcess.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a `Process` object that represents the new process and can call the `Kill` method on it if you need to get rid of it.

The alternative is to change this to non-static and have the class instance terminate the process when requested.  Depending on what you're doing it might make sense to implement `IDisposable`:

```
public class MyProcess : IDisposable
{
    private Process myProcess = null;

    ~MyProcess()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose(bool dispose)
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (myProcess != null)
        {
            if (!myProcess.HasExited)
                myProcess.Kill();
            myProcess.Dispose();
            myProcess = null;
        }
    }

    public bool LaunchProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\example.bat";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            myProcess.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

That should ensure that the process doesn't outlive your own program.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the `"Exit"` command to the batch file

Comment: Question seems to be about how to terminate the batch file externally, not have the batch file end itself.

Comment: Using Exit in the batch file will ensure that it doesn't terminate the batch file prematurely. Else process.Kill is most likely the way to go